# Is using a tobit regression appropriate for structured missing data?

Tags: r, missing-data, tobit-regression

I have a data set with a significant amount of missing data and that missing data is not random.

I decided to change these NA values to 999 and apply a Tobit with right censoring after a cut-off point at the maximum recorded values. I'm questioning whether this is an appropriate application of a Tobit regression. Running models without including the missing data leaves out important data. It is expected that the missing outcome data would have been high.

I'm struggling to find good explanations and applications of a tobit analysis, especially with structured missing data. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This probably is not a good application of Tobit regression.

Your situation is probably better modeled as a competing-risks survival model. The competing "risks" here are recovery and discharge to a rehabilitation center. Those would seem to be mutually exclusive events (unless the same individual has been admitted at more than 1 time).

This [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) for the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) shows how to build such a model with readily available tools. Section 3.1 of the vignette seems to be most closely related to your situation.